# Python if statement checking for a £ pound sign in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, unicode

I have the following line which is causing me problems:

`if "Total £" in studentfees:`

returns:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

How can I get around this?

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following to the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also:

```
if u"Total £" in studentfees:
```

Comment: @Hyflex If this answers your question you should accept it as correct.

Comment: Just what I needed, you are a king and a gentlemen